# R shiny flexible drop-down selection tab

Tags: r, shiny

I am working on an R Shiny app that will serve as a carbon footprint calculator. In the flights part, I have 3 flight types and 4 class flight options. However, not all flight types offer all classes, and this corresponds to the emission factors in the emission_factors list. Therefore, for example, when selecting a domestic flight, I would like to have only the economy class as an available option. How can I achieve this? I know I will need to use some sort of if statements, but I do not have enough knowledge about them.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Carbon Footprint Calculator"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Daily Commuting", tabName = "daily_commuting", startExpanded = TRUE,
               menuSubItem("By vehicle type", tabName = "by_vehicle_type"),
               menuSubItem("By fuel consumption", tabName = "by_fuel_consumption")),
      menuItem("Business Travel", tabName = "business_travel",
               menuSubItem("By vehicle type", tabName = "BT_by_vehicle_type"),
               menuSubItem("By fuel consumption", tabName = "BT_by_fuel_consumption")),
      menuItem("Results", tabName = "results")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".input-set {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin-right: 20px;
      }"))),
    tags$head(tags$style(HTML("#text {
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      }"))),
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "by_vehicle_type",
              h3("Cars"),
              actionButton("add_car", "Add more cars"),
              actionButton("remove_car", "Remove car"),
              div(id = "car_inputs"),
              verbatimTextOutput("text"),
              hr(),
              h3("Motorbikes"),
              actionButton("add_bike", "Add more motorbikes"),
              actionButton("remove_bike", "Remove motorbike"),
              div(id = "bike_inputs"),
              hr(),
              h3("Taxi"),
              actionButton("add_taxi", "Add more taxi"),
              actionButton("remove_taxi", "Remove taxi"),
              div(id = "taxi_inputs"),
              hr(),
              h3("Buses"),
              actionButton("add_bus", "Add more bus"),
              actionButton("remove_bus", "Remove bus"),
              div(id = "bus_inputs"),
              hr(),
              h3("Rail"),
              actionButton("add_rail", "Add more rail"),
              actionButton("remove_rail", "Remove rail"),
              div(id = "rail_inputs")),
      tabItem(tabName = "by_fuel_consumption",
              h3("Fuel Consumption"),
              numericInput("petrol_fuel", "Enter your daily petrol consumption in litres:", value = 0, min = 0),
              numericInput("diesel_fuel", "Enter your daily diesel consumption in litres:", value = 0, min = 0),
              numericInput("electricity_fuel", "Enter your daily electricity consumption in litres:", value = 0, min = 0),
              numericInput("cng_fuel", "Enter your daily CNG consumption in litres:", value = 0, min = 0),
              numericInput("lpg_fuel", "Enter your daily LPG consumption in litres:", value = 0, min = 0),
              numericInput("lng_fuel", "Enter your daily LNG consumption in litres:", value = 0, min = 0)),
      tabItem(tabName = "BT_by_vehicle_type",
              h3("Cars"),
              actionButton("add_BT_car", "Add more cars"),
              actionButton("remove_BT_car", "Remove car"),
              div(id = "BT_car_inputs"),
              verbatimTextOutput("BT_text"),
              hr(),
              h3("Motorbikes"),
              actionButton("add_BT_bike", "Add more motorbikes"),
              actionButton("remove_BT_bike", "Remove motorbike"),
              div(id = "BT_bike_inputs"),
              hr(),
              h3("Taxi"),
              actionButton("add_BT_taxi", "Add more taxi"),
              actionButton("remove_BT_taxi", "Remove taxi"),
              div(id = "BT_taxi_inputs"),
              hr(),
              h3("Buses"),
              actionButton("add_BT_bus", "Add more bus"),
              actionButton("remove_BT_bus", "Remove bus"),
              div(id = "BT_bus_inputs"),
              hr(),
              h3("Rail"),
              actionButton("add_BT_rail", "Add more rail"),
              actionButton("remove_BT_rail", "Remove rail"),
              div(id = "BT_rail_inputs"),
              hr(),
              h3("Flights"),
              actionButton("add_BT_flights", "Add more"),
              actionButton("remove_BT_flights", "Remove"),
              div(id = "BT_flights_inputs"),
              hr()),
      tabItem(tabName = "BT_by_fuel_consumption",
              h3("Fuel Consumption"),
              numericInput("BT_petrol_fuel", "Enter your daily petrol consumption in litres:", value = 0, min = 0),
              numericInput("BT_diesel_fuel", "Enter your daily diesel consumption in litres:", value = 0, min = 0),
              numericInput("BT_electricity_fuel", "Enter your daily electricity consumption in litres:", value = 0, min = 0),
              numericInput("BT_cng_fuel", "Enter your daily CNG consumption in litres:", value = 0, min = 0),
              numericInput("BT_lpg_fuel", "Enter your daily LPG consumption in litres:", value = 0, min = 0),
              numericInput("BT_lng_fuel", "Enter your daily LNG consumption in litres:", value = 0, min = 0)),
      tabItem(tabName = "hotel_stays",
              textInput("hotel_nights", "Number of hotel nights per year", "0")),
      tabItem(tabName = "food",
              textInput("meat_meals", "Number of meat-based meals per week", "0")),
      tabItem(tabName = "results",
              verbatimTextOutput("footprint_result"))
    )
  )
) 

server <- function(input, output, session) { 
  output$text <- renderText({ 
    "CNG: compressed natural gass\nLPG: liquefied petroleum gass" 
  })
  output$text2 <- renderText({ 
    "Example: If an employee works at home 2 times a week and you want to calculate the\nmonthly emissions, enter 64 in the cell (2 days * 4 weeks * 8 hours)." 
  })
  
  car_counter <- reactiveVal(0) 
  bike_counter <- reactiveVal(0) 
  taxi_counter <- reactiveVal(0) 
  bus_counter <- reactiveVal(0) 
  rail_counter <- reactiveVal(0) 
  
  observeEvent(input$add_car, { 
    car_counter(car_counter() + 1) 
    ns <- NS(paste0("car_inputs", car_counter())) 
    insertUI( 
      selector = "#car_inputs", 
      ui = tags$div(id = ns("car_div"), class = "input-set", 
                    selectInput(ns("car_type"), "Choose your car type:", 
                                choices = list("Electric" = "electric", "Hybrid" = "hybrid", "Petrol" = "petrol", "Diesel" = "diesel")), 
                    selectInput(ns("car_size"), "Choose your car size:", 
                                choices = list("Small" = "small", "Medium" = "medium", "Large" = "large")), 
                    numericInput(ns("km_driven"), "Enter the number of kilometers you drive daily:", value = 0, min = 0) 
      ) 
    ) 
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(input$add_bike, { 
    bike_counter(bike_counter() + 1) 
    ns <- NS(paste0("bike_inputs", bike_counter())) 
    insertUI( 
      selector = "#bike_inputs", 
      ui = tags$div(id = ns("bike_div"), class = "input-set", 
                    selectInput(ns("bike_size"), "Choose your motorbike size:", 
                                choices = list("Small" = "small", "Medium" = "medium", "Large" = "large")), 
                    numericInput(ns("km_driven"), "Enter the number of kilometers you drive daily:", value = 0, min = 0) 
      ) 
    ) 
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(input$add_taxi, { 
    taxi_counter(taxi_counter() + 1) 
    ns <- NS(paste0("taxi_inputs", taxi_counter())) 
    insertUI( 
      selector = "#taxi_inputs", 
      ui = tags$div(id = ns("taxi_div"), class = "input-set", 
                    selectInput(ns("taxi_type"), "Choose taxi type:", 
                                choices = list("Electric" = "electric", "Regular" = "regular")), 
                    numericInput(ns("km_driven"), "Enter the number of kilometers you travel by taxi daily:", value = 0, min = 0) 
      ) 
    ) 
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(input$add_bus, { 
    bus_counter(bus_counter() + 1) 
    ns <- NS(paste0("bus_inputs", bus_counter())) 
    insertUI( 
      selector = "#bus_inputs", 
      ui = tags$div(id = ns("bus_div"), class = "input-set", 
                    selectInput(ns("bus_type"), "Choose bus type:", 
                                choices = list("Average Local Bus" = "local_bus", "Long Distance Bus" = "long_distance_bus")), 
                    numericInput(ns("km_driven"), "Enter the number of kilometers you travel by bus daily:", value = 0, min = 0) 
      ) 
    ) 
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(input$add_rail, { 
    rail_counter(rail_counter() + 1) 
    ns <- NS(paste0("rail_inputs", rail_counter())) 
    insertUI( 
      selector = "#rail_inputs", 
      ui = tags$div(id = ns("rail_div"), class = "input-set", 
                    selectInput(ns("rail_type"), "Choose rail type:", 
                                choices = list("National" = "national", "International" = "international")), 
                    numericInput(ns("km_traveled"), "Enter the number of kilometers you travel by rail daily:", value = 0, min = 0) 
      ) 
    ) 
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(input$remove_car, { 
    if (car_counter() > 0) { 
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#car_inputs", car_counter(), "-car_div")) 
      car_counter(car_counter() - 1) 
    } 
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(input$remove_bike, { 
    if (bike_counter() > 0) { 
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#bike_inputs", bike_counter(), "-bike_div")) 
      bike_counter(bike_counter() - 1) 
    } 
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(input$remove_taxi, { 
    if (taxi_counter() > 0) { 
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#taxi_inputs", taxi_counter(), "-taxi_div")) 
      taxi_counter(taxi_counter() - 1) 
    } 
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(input$remove_bus, { 
    if (bus_counter() > 0) { 
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#bus_inputs", bus_counter(), "-bus_div")) 
      bus_counter(bus_counter() - 1) 
    } 
  }) 
  
  observeEvent(input$remove_rail, { 
    if (rail_counter() > 0) { 
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#rail_inputs", rail_counter(), "-rail_div")) 
      rail_counter(rail_counter() - 1) 
    } 
  }) 
  
  emission_factors <- list("electric" = list("small" = 0.001, "medium" = 0.0015, "large" = 0.002), 
                           "hybrid" = list("small" = 0.002, "medium" = 0.0025, "large" = 0.003), 
                           "petrol" = list("small" = 0.0025, "medium" = 0.003, "large" = 0.0035), 
                           "diesel" = list("small" = 0.003, "medium" = 0.0035, "large" = 0.004), 
                           "bike" = list("small" = 0.0005, "medium" = 0.0008, "large" = 0.001), 
                           "fuel" = list("petrol" = 2.31, "diesel" = 2.68, "electricity" = 0.475, "cng" = 1.85, "lpg" = 1.51, "lng" = 1.99),  # kg CO2e per litre 
                           "electricity" = 0.475,  # kg CO2e per kWh 
                           "heat_steam" = 56,  # kg CO2e per GJ 
                           "water" = 0.344,  # kg CO2e per cubic meter 
                           "waste_water" = 0.3,  # kg CO2e per cubic meter 
                           "paper" = list("Recycling" = 0.1, "Composting" = 0.2, "Landfill" = 0.3),  # kg CO2e per kg 
                           "plastic" = list("Recycling" = 0.05, "Composting" = 0.1, "Landfill" = 0.2),  # kg CO2e per kg 
                           "glass" = list("Recycling" = 0.15, "Composting" = 0.25, "Landfill" = 0.35),  # kg CO2e per kg 
                           "organic" = list("Recycling" = 0.03, "Composting" = 0.05, "Landfill" = 0.08),  # kg CO2e per kg 
                           "taxi" = list("electric" = 0.0015, "regular" = 0.002),  # kg CO2e per km 
                           "bus" = list("local_bus" = 0.001, "long_distance_bus" = 0.0015),  # kg CO2e per km 
                           "rail" = list("national" = 0.03, "international" = 0.06),  # kg CO2e per km
                           "domestic" = list("economy" = 0.272576785234899),
                           "int_EU" = list("economy" = 0.182869354362416, "business" = 0.274302877852349),
                           "int_world" = list("economy" = 0.134643330308725, "prem_economy" = 0.21541942147651, "business" = 0.390443205369128, "first" = 0.5385424)
  ) 
  
  BT_car_counter <- reactiveVal(0) 
  BT_bike_counter <- reactiveVal(0) 
  BT_taxi_counter <- reactiveVal(0) 
  BT_bus_counter <- reactiveVal(0) 
  BT_rail_counter <- reactiveVal(0)
  BT_flights_counter <- reactiveVal(0)
  
  # Business Travel observeEvents
  observeEvent(input$add_BT_car, { 
    BT_car_counter(BT_car_counter() + 1) 
    ns <- NS(paste0("BT_car_inputs", BT_car_counter())) 
    insertUI( 
      selector = "#BT_car_inputs", 
      ui = tags$div(id = ns("car_div"), class = "input-set", 
                    selectInput(ns("car_type"), "Choose your car type:", 
                                choices = list("Electric" = "electric", "Hybrid" = "hybrid", "Petrol" = "petrol", "Diesel" = "diesel")), 
                    selectInput(ns("car_size"), "Choose your car size:", 
                                choices = list("Small" = "small", "Medium" = "medium", "Large" = "large")), 
                    numericInput(ns("km_driven"), "Enter the number of kilometers you drive daily:", value = 0, min = 0) 
      ) 
    ) 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add_BT_bike, { 
    BT_bike_counter(BT_bike_counter() + 1) 
    ns <- NS(paste0("BT_bike_inputs", BT_bike_counter())) 
    insertUI( 
      selector = "#BT_bike_inputs", 
      ui = tags$div(id = ns("bike_div"), class = "input-set", 
                    selectInput(ns("bike_size"), "Choose your motorbike size:", 
                                choices = list("Small" = "small", "Medium" = "medium", "Large" = "large")), 
                    numericInput(ns("km_driven"), "Enter the number of kilometers you drive daily:", value = 0, min = 0) 
      ) 
    ) 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add_BT_taxi, { 
    BT_taxi_counter(BT_taxi_counter() + 1) 
    ns <- NS(paste0("BT_taxi_inputs", BT_taxi_counter())) 
    insertUI( 
      selector = "#BT_taxi_inputs", 
      ui = tags$div(id = ns("taxi_div"), class = "input-set", 
                    selectInput(ns("taxi_type"), "Choose taxi type:", 
                                choices = list("Electric" = "electric", "Regular" = "regular")), 
                    numericInput(ns("km_driven"), "Enter the number of kilometers you travel by taxi daily:", value = 0, min = 0) 
      ) 
    ) 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add_BT_bus, { 
    BT_bus_counter(BT_bus_counter() + 1) 
    ns <- NS(paste0("BT_bus_inputs", BT_bus_counter())) 
    insertUI( 
      selector = "#BT_bus_inputs", 
      ui = tags$div(id = ns("bus_div"), class = "input-set", 
                    selectInput(ns("bus_type"), "Choose bus type:", 
                                choices = list("Average Local Bus" = "local_bus", "Long Distance Bus" = "long_distance_bus")), 
                    numericInput(ns("km_driven"), "Enter the number of kilometers you travel by bus daily:", value = 0, min = 0) 
      ) 
    ) 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add_BT_rail, { 
    BT_rail_counter(BT_rail_counter() + 1) 
    ns <- NS(paste0("BT_rail_inputs", BT_rail_counter())) 
    insertUI( 
      selector = "#BT_rail_inputs", 
      ui = tags$div(id = ns("flights_div"), class = "input-set", 
                    selectInput(ns("rail_type"), "Choose rail type:", 
                                choices = list("National" = "national", "International" = "international")), 
                    numericInput(ns("km_traveled"), "Enter the number of kilometers you travel by rail daily:", value = 0, min = 0) 
      ) 
    ) 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$add_BT_flights, { 
    BT_flights_counter(BT_flights_counter() + 1) 
    ns <- NS(paste0("BT_flights_inputs", BT_flights_counter())) 
    insertUI( 
      selector = "#BT_flights_inputs", 
      ui = tags$div(id = ns("flights_div"), class = "input-set", 
                    selectInput(ns("flights_type"), "Choose your flight type:", 
                                choices = list("Domestic" = "domestic", "International filghts inside of Europe" = "int_EU", "International filghts outside of Europe" = "int_world")), 
                    selectInput(ns("class"), "Choose your class:", 
                                choices = list("Economy" = "economy", "Premium economy" = "prem_economy", "Business" = "business", "First" = "first")), 
                    numericInput(ns("km_driven"), "Enter the number of kilometers:", value = 0, min = 0) 
      ) 
    ) 
  })
  
  # Observers for removing Business Travel input sets
  observeEvent(input$remove_BT_car, { 
    if (BT_car_counter() > 0) { 
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#BT_car_inputs", BT_car_counter(), "-car_div")) 
      BT_car_counter(BT_car_counter() - 1) 
    } 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$remove_BT_bike, { 
    if (BT_bike_counter() > 0) { 
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#BT_bike_inputs", BT_bike_counter(), "-bike_div")) 
      BT_bike_counter(BT_bike_counter() - 1) 
    } 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$remove_BT_taxi, { 
    if (BT_taxi_counter() > 0) { 
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#BT_taxi_inputs", BT_taxi_counter(), "-taxi_div")) 
      BT_taxi_counter(BT_taxi_counter() - 1) 
    } 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$remove_BT_bus, { 
    if (BT_bus_counter() > 0) { 
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#BT_bus_inputs", BT_bus_counter(), "-bus_div")) 
      BT_bus_counter(BT_bus_counter() - 1) 
    } 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$remove_BT_rail, { 
    if (BT_rail_counter() > 0) { 
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#BT_rail_inputs", BT_rail_counter(), "-rail_div")) 
      BT_rail_counter(BT_rail_counter() - 1) 
    } 
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$remove_BT_flights, { 
    if (BT_flights_counter() > 0) { 
      removeUI(selector = paste0("#BT_flights_inputs", BT_flights_counter(), "-flights_div")) 
      BT_flights_counter(BT_flights_counter() - 1) 
    } 
  })
  
  footprint <- reactive({ 
    n_cars <- car_counter() 
    n_bikes <- bike_counter() 
    n_taxis <- taxi_counter() 
    n_buses <- bus_counter() 
    n_rails <- rail_counter() 
    daily_commuting_emissions <- 0 
    
    if (n_cars > 0) { 
      daily_commuting_emissions <- daily_commuting_emissions + sum(sapply(1:n_cars, function(i) { 
        ns <- NS(paste0("car_inputs", i)) 
        car_emission_factor <- emission_factors[[input[[ns("car_type")]]]][[input[[ns("car_size")]]]] 
        as.numeric(input[[ns("km_driven")]]) * car_emission_factor 
      })) 
    } 
    
    if (n_bikes > 0) { 
      daily_commuting_emissions <- daily_commuting_emissions + sum(sapply(1:n_bikes, function(i) { 
        ns <- NS(paste0("bike_inputs", i)) 
        bike_emission_factor <- emission_factors[["bike"]][[input[[ns("bike_size")]]]] 
        as.numeric(input[[ns("km_driven")]]) * bike_emission_factor 
      })) 
    } 
    
    if (n_taxis > 0) { 
      daily_commuting_emissions <- daily_commuting_emissions + sum(sapply(1:n_taxis, function(i) { 
        ns <- NS(paste0("taxi_inputs", i)) 
        taxi_emission_factor <- emission_factors[["taxi"]][[input[[ns("taxi_type")]]]] 
        as.numeric(input[[ns("km_driven")]]) * taxi_emission_factor 
      })) 
    } 
    
    if (n_buses > 0) { 
      daily_commuting_emissions <- daily_commuting_emissions + sum(sapply(1:n_buses, function(i) { 
        ns <- NS(paste0("bus_inputs", i)) 
        bus_emission_factor <- emission_factors[["bus"]][[input[[ns("bus_type")]]]] 
        as.numeric(input[[ns("km_driven")]]) * bus_emission_factor 
      })) 
    } 
    
    if (n_rails > 0) { 
      daily_commuting_emissions <- daily_commuting_emissions + sum(sapply(1:n_rails, function(i) { 
        ns <- NS(paste0("rail_inputs", i)) 
        rail_emission_factor <- emission_factors[["rail"]][[input[[ns("rail_type")]]]] 
        as.numeric(input[[ns("km_traveled")]]) * rail_emission_factor 
      })) 
    } 
    
    fuel_consumption_emissions = as.numeric(input$petrol_fuel) * emission_factors[["fuel"]][["petrol"]] + 
      as.numeric(input$diesel_fuel) * emission_factors[["fuel"]][["diesel"]] + 
      as.numeric(input$electricity_fuel) * emission_factors[["fuel"]][["electricity"]] + 
      as.numeric(input$cng_fuel) * emission_factors[["fuel"]][["cng"]] + 
      as.numeric(input$lpg_fuel) * emission_factors[["fuel"]][["lpg"]] + 
      as.numeric(input$lng_fuel) * emission_factors[["fuel"]][["lng"]]
    
    BT_fuel_consumption_emissions = as.numeric(input$BT_petrol_fuel) * emission_factors[["fuel"]][["petrol"]] + 
      as.numeric(input$BT_diesel_fuel) * emission_factors[["fuel"]][["diesel"]] + 
      as.numeric(input$BT_electricity_fuel) * emission_factors[["fuel"]][["electricity"]] + 
      as.numeric(input$BT_cng_fuel) * emission_factors[["fuel"]][["cng"]] + 
      as.numeric(input$BT_lpg_fuel) * emission_factors[["fuel"]][["lpg"]] + 
      as.numeric(input$BT_lng_fuel) * emission_factors[["fuel"]][["lng"]] 
    
    # Compute the emissions from business travel
    n_BT_cars <- BT_car_counter() 
    n_BT_bikes <- BT_bike_counter() 
    n_BT_taxis <- BT_taxi_counter() 
    n_BT_buses <- BT_bus_counter() 
    n_BT_rails <- BT_rail_counter()
    n_BT_flights <- BT_flights_counter()
    BT_emissions <- 0 
    
    if (n_BT_cars > 0) { 
      BT_emissions <- BT_emissions + sum(sapply(1:n_BT_cars, function(i) { 
        ns <- NS(paste0("BT_car_inputs", i)) 
        car_emission_factor <- emission_factors[[input[[ns("car_type")]]]][[input[[ns("car_size")]]]] 
        as.numeric(input[[ns("km_driven")]]) * car_emission_factor 
      })) 
    } 
    
    if (n_BT_bikes > 0) { 
      BT_emissions <- BT_emissions + sum(sapply(1:n_BT_bikes, function(i) { 
        ns <- NS(paste0("BT_bike_inputs", i)) 
        bike_emission_factor <- emission_factors[["bike"]][[input[[ns("bike_size")]]]] 
        as.numeric(input[[ns("km_driven")]]) * bike_emission_factor 
      })) 
    } 
    
    if (n_BT_taxis > 0) { 
      BT_emissions <- BT_emissions + sum(sapply(1:n_BT_taxis, function(i) { 
        ns <- NS(paste0("BT_taxi_inputs", i)) 
        taxi_emission_factor <- emission_factors[["taxi"]][[input[[ns("taxi_type")]]]] 
        as.numeric(input[[ns("km_driven")]]) * taxi_emission_factor 
      })) 
    } 
    
    if (n_BT_buses > 0) { 
      BT_emissions <- BT_emissions + sum(sapply(1:n_BT_buses, function(i) { 
        ns <- NS(paste0("BT_bus_inputs", i)) 
        bus_emission_factor <- emission_factors[["bus"]][[input[[ns("bus_type")]]]] 
        as.numeric(input[[ns("km_driven")]]) * bus_emission_factor 
      })) 
    } 
    
    if (n_BT_rails > 0) { 
      BT_emissions <- BT_emissions + sum(sapply(1:n_BT_rails, function(i) { 
        ns <- NS(paste0("BT_rail_inputs", i)) 
        rail_emission_factor <- emission_factors[["rail"]][[input[[ns("rail_type")]]]] 
        as.numeric(input[[ns("km_traveled")]]) * rail_emission_factor 
      })) 
    }
    
    if (n_BT_flights > 0) { 
      BT_emissions <- BT_emissions + sum(sapply(1:n_BT_flights, function(i) { 
        ns <- NS(paste0("BT_flights_inputs", i)) 
        flights_emission_factor <- emission_factors[[input[[ns("flights_type")]]]][[input[[ns("class")]]]] 
        as.numeric(input[[ns("km_driven")]]) * flights_emission_factor 
      })) 
    }
    
    total_footprint = daily_commuting_emissions + fuel_consumption_emissions +
      BT_fuel_consumption_emissions + BT_emissions
    
    return(total_footprint)
  })
  
  output$footprint_result <- renderPrint({
    paste("Your estimated annual carbon footprint is:", round(footprint(), 2), "kg CO2e.")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you're trying to achieve when you post the entire codebase. Can you produce a simple example of what needs changing and how you would like it to change?